# I have a problem with my tooltip positions, always show the position in the same spot

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, styled-components

This is the code, is a simple tooltip, but I'm freeze here!! Help

```
const StyledTooltip = styled.div`
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
background: #666565;

`
const Element = styled.div`
background: #666565;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
line-height: 0;
width: fit-content;

`
const Container = styled.div<{ width: number; height: number }>`
position: relative;
cursor: pointer;
white-space: normal;
box-sizing: border-box;
line-height: normal;
width: fit-content;

&:hover > ${StyledTooltip} {
    visibility: visible;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: ${props => `${props.height}px;`} ;
    width: ${props => `${props.width}px;`} ;
    
}

&::after :hover > ${StyledTooltip}[position= 'left']{
    right: calc(100% - 50px);
    top: -5px;
        &::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-top: 7px solid #666565;
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        top: 40%;
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        right:-10px;
}
    
}
&::after :hover > ${StyledTooltip}[position='right']{
    left: calc(100% - 50px);
    &::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-top: 7px solid #666565;
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        transform: rotate(91deg);
        bottom: calc(50% - 5px);
        left:-9px;
}
}
&::after :hover > ${StyledTooltip}[position = 'top']{
    bottom: calc(100% - 15px);
    right: calc(100% - 15px);
        &::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-top: 7px solid #666565;
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        bottom: -6px;
        left:calc(48% - 7px) ;

}
}
&::after :hover > ${StyledTooltip}[position = 'bottom']{
    top: calc(100% + 50px);
    &::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        border-bottom: 7px solid #666565;
        border-right: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: 7px solid transparent;
        bottom: 58px;
        left:calc(54% - 8px) ;

}
}
`

type ToolTip ={
    children: JSX.Element,
    description: string,
    position?: 'left'| 'right'| 'top'| 'bottom'
}

export const ToolTipHover = (props: ToolTip) => {
    const tooltipRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
    const [position, setPosition] = useState<string>('top')
    const minWidth = 150
    const minHeight = 150

    useEffect(() => {
        if(tooltipRef.current) {
            const top = tooltipRef.current.offsetTop
            const left = tooltipRef.current.offsetLeft
            const bottom = window.innerHeight - top - tooltipRef.current.offsetHeight
            const right = window.innerWidth - left - tooltipRef.current.offsetWidth
            console.log({
                top, bottom, left, right
            })
            if(top > minHeight && bottom < top) return setPosition('top')
            if(bottom > minHeight && top < bottom ) return setPosition('bottom')
            if(left > minWidth && right < left) return setPosition('left')
            if(right > minWidth && left < right ) return setPosition('right')
        }
    },[tooltipRef.current])
    console.log(position)
    return (
    <Container ref={tooltipRef} width={minWidth} height={minHeight} >
<Element >{props.children}</Element> 
        <StyledTooltip position={props.position || position}>
        {props.description}
        </StyledTooltip>
        
    </Container>
    )
}
```

It supposed to show the tooltip in the screen, depending where is element, but whenever the element is, the tooltip still show up in the same spot, i think the position var is wrong or I'm calling the positions in the wrong way or something like that.